# Set web browser TextBox (WinForms) to be transparent via WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm trying to add a watermark to a web browser that I host with "WindowsFormsHost" in a WPF file.
I implemented a control template that contains a label and a web browser, but I can't change the Background of the web browser to be Transparent / opacity. How can I set this change?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a watermark, but you cannot set the web browser control as transparent. WPF uses a rendering mode where the last defined element is painted on top, so you could add a Popup control (WPF) and do the following for example to 'paint' a watermark on top of the web browser control hosted inside the WindowsFormsHost.

XAML:

```
    <Window x:Class="WebBrowserWindowsFormsNet48.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WebBrowserWindowsFormsNet48"
        xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1000">
    <Grid Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <WindowsFormsHost Name="wb">
            <WindowsFormsHost.Child>
                <wf:WebBrowser Url="https://www.google.no" ScriptErrorsSuppressed="True" />
            </WindowsFormsHost.Child>
        </WindowsFormsHost>

        <Popup 
            IsOpen="True"
            AllowsTransparency="True"
            Placement="Relative"            
            x:Name="WatermarkPopup"   
            Height="30"
            Width="200"
            PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
            PopupAnimation="Slide">
            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                <TextBlock x:Name="lblWatermark" FontSize="20" Foreground="Silver" FontFamily="Impact, Haettenschweiler, Franklin Gothic Bold, Charcoal, Helvetica Inserat, Bitstream Vera Sans Bold, Arial Black, sans serif" Text="Watermark goes here !" />
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
     
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You could add some event handlers that react upon window being moved and resized so the watermark position is updated and stays the relatively same position.

```
    /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SizeChanged += MainWindow_SizeChanged;
        this.LocationChanged += MainWindow_LocationChanged;
    }

private void MainWindow_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WatermarkPopup.HorizontalOffset = this.Left / 2 - WatermarkPopup.Width / 2;
    WatermarkPopup.VerticalOffset = this.Top / 2 - WatermarkPopup.Height / 2;
}

private void MainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
   WatermarkPopup.HorizontalOffset = SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth / 2 - WatermarkPopup.Width / 2;
   WatermarkPopup.VerticalOffset = SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight / 2 - WatermarkPopup.Height / 2;
}
```

You want to refine this code a bit and delay the updating of the popup position as this gave me heavy flickering, and it needs refinement anyways. But maybe my answer helps you achieve your goal with some polishing work.

[image: Watermark Windows forms web browser inside WPF]
In the picture, you see the watermark as 'Watermark goes here!'. This is a WPF control (Label) painted above the Web Browser. Note that controlling the transparency in case you want a background image for example inside a WindowsFormsHost is not supported.  (I have search the web for this, and could not find any examples)